# JTable setting a default editor for a custom class

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I am having an issue with trying to set a default JTable cell editor for a custom class. I have several custom columns (numbers, strings and booleans). For the number types I use a my own cell editors and for the boolean and string types I just wanted to use the default ones provided by the JTable class.

I have the following code in the setup of my table:

```
JTable table;
....
table.setDefaultEditor(MyBoolean.class, table.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class));
table.setDefaultRenderer(MyBoolean.class, table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
table.setDefaultEditor(MyString.class, table.getDefaultEditor(String.class);
table.setDefaultRenderer(MyString.class, table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class);
```

The boolean type works as expected and I can click on the tickbox and have it turn on and off. The string type displays but will not let me edit. In my model I have it so that all columns return true for editable.

If I add the following to my model:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex){
    Class<?> clz = columns.get(columnIndex).getClass();
    if(clz.isAssignableFrom(MyString.class)){
        return String.class;
    }
    return clz;
}
```

I can now edit the strings as expected.

My question: Why does setting the default editor not work for the string class but does for the boolean class? Why do I have to have a special case in the getColumnClass method in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why it was behaving the way I described originally. It finally clicked when I looked at the `setValueAt` method:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
   rows.get(rowIndex).getValues().set(columnIndex, aValue);
   fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
}
```

and noticed that `Object` was an instance of `MyString` and the result in the cell came from `Object.toString()`.

The reason `MyString` came through to the method is because the `GenericEditor` in `JTable` (which covers the `String` class) has the method `getTableCellEditorComponent` which creates a `java.lang.reflect.Constructor` object that is used to instantiate new instances of the objects allowed in this column. `MyString` column class had a constructor that took a `String` and hence it returned a new `MyString` column instance to the `setValueAt` method. When I changed the code in `getColumnClass` (as shown above) to return `String.class`, a new instance of `String` was created when the editing stopped and it was passed to the `setValueAt` method and hence correctly displaced in the cell.

Definitely learned a lot about JTables with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are extending `DefaultTableModel`, note that `getColumnClass()`, inherited from [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#getColumnClass-int-), "returns `Object.class` regardless of `columnIndex`." As noted [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), `Object` "is rendered by a label that displays the object's string value." There is no default editor for `Object`. In particular, "To specify more precise column types, the table model must define the `getColumnClass()` method appropriately."

Comment: I am extending `AbstractTableModel` and have overridden the `getColumnClass()` method as in the example above and it does return the correct class values as expected. The problem is, I have set the editor for `MyString.class` to be the same as the one for `String.class` and it is not working. It only works when I fool the table into believing that the column that should return `MyString.class` is actually a `String.class`.

Comment: @john this idea can works, the problem is in rest of your code

Comment: See the implementation of [`getTableCellEditorComponent()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/javax/swing/JTable.java).